# images becoming attachments in email

Tags: php, drupal

I am sending emails using email templates when users register and when request forgotten passwords. For email sending I am using `phpmailer`. The emails are being received but all images are being sent as attachments. Instead I would like the images to be part of the email. I have not used any attachment code.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$pathth = drupal_get_path('theme','vwr');   
$mail = new phpmailer(); 
$mail->IsSendmail();
$mail->IsSMTP();

$send_mail = 0;
$body = $mail->getFile($path.'/email_templates/approval_email.tpl.php');
$body = str_replace("base_path", $path, $body);
$body = str_replace("url", $url, $body);
$body = eregi_replace("[\]", '', $body);

$mail->From = "VWRsuppliercentral@VWR.com";
$mail->FromName = "vwr";
$mail->Subject = "VWR Forget Password";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress("$email");
$mail->Send()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the attached images showing in your e-mail, as well as displaying as attachments? If so...

Embedded images in an e-mail *are* MIME attachments. Some e-mail viewers will detect if the MIME attachment is for use inside the e-mail and hide the attachment icon from the user, others won't. As far as I know you don't have control over that.

You can instead refer to images stored on an external server. For security reasons most e-mail clients will not load these by default and your e-mails will look messy.

In other words it ain't broke.